# How to find cause of registration failed of a dll

Tags: c++, dll, directshow

I'm playing with `DirectShow` filters from here: http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm.
The example `Capture Source Filter` works fine if I use the included binary on a Windows 10 64-bit machine.

Instead, re-compiling the source code leads to the following error when I try to register the filter:

> The module "..." was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

As far as I know this is might due to some mismatches in architectures.

This is what I did:

1. from here: https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next, I compiled both x86_MT and x64_MT lib for `BaseClasses`
2. I created a new project, added the existing `Capture Source Filter` source files, added the correct paths for includes and libs of the previous point, set the code generation to MT and build again both x86_MT and x64_MT.
3. I tried to register the output filters with `DirectShow Filter Manager` (http://www.softella.com/dsfm/index.en.htm) - it worked fine with the pre-compiler binary. Of course I've unregistered the old filter before try with the fresh compiled one.

`Dependency Walker` seems say nothing interesting. It complains about the missing of a lot of `API-MS-WIN*.dll` but they are actually on file-system and anyway those errors there are also for the working binaries.

At this point, to avoid to give random trials, what one should do to narrow down the source of errors?
Is there any tool available that might help me to understand where I was wrong?

### UPDATE

I found the root of the problem: the original code uses a `def` file to export the function, but they aren't actually exported.
This is the `def` file:

```
LIBRARY     Vcam.ax
EXPORTS
    DllMain                 PRIVATE
    DllGetClassObject       PRIVATE
    DllCanUnloadNow         PRIVATE
    DllRegisterServer       PRIVATE
    DllUnregisterServer     PRIVATE
```

but adding this file to the sources isn't enough.
Reading other posts here leads me to understand I need to use `__declspec(dllexport)` instead of the `def` file.

Hence I added an header file for the dll.cpp with this code:

```
#pragma once

#include <winnt.h>
#include <minwindef.h>

#define DLLEXPORT   __declspec(dllexport) 

STDAPI DLLEXPORT DllRegisterServer();
STDAPI DLLEXPORT DllUnregisterServer();
DLLEXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD  dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved);
STDAPI DLLEXPORT DllCanUnloadNow();
STDAPI DLLEXPORT DllGetClassObject(__in REFCLSID rClsID, __in REFIID riid, __deref_out void **pv);
```

But still `dumpbin` tells me that functions are not exported.

Answer (score 1):

Here is described how to use the `def` files:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34c30xs1.aspx

The missing step was add it to Property Page > Linker > Input > Module Definition File.

Answer (score 0):

> The module "..." was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

With such error Dependency Walker should be able to confirm whether `DllRegisterServer` is available or not - the utility shows exported functions.

If the function is exported, the problem might be with dependency or wrong bitness, that is the problem that results in inability to `LoadLibrary` the DLL.

If the function is not exported, the project is likely to be missing a .DEF file or otherwise does not define an exportable symbol (e.g. using [respective `#pragma`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k30y2k5.aspx)).